# An error on a form submit allows the submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form defined in HTML which can be submitted with a submit button.

I also have a jquery handler in which there is a logger on a non existing object.

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    console.log(nosuchobject);
    return false;
});
```

With the logger in place, the form is submitted and the browser changes page. But without the logger, the form is not submitted.

My guess is that when there is an error in the logger the returned value is not false. But is it true ? And how come an error allows for a form to be submitted anyway ?

Comment: if `nosuchobject` is not defined it will trigger an error, then `return false;` will not be reached so the form will be submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get a js error in the submit function the code after the error won't be executed what means that it does not return a false. You can prevent the form submission at the start of your function like this:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // it does not matter if there is an error now.
    console.log(nosuchobject);
});
```

You should still write your code so it runs without errors.

Comment: Indeed, I removed the logger that was giving an error. It is legacy code I'm looking at. I don't want to prevent the form submission. My takeaway is the error occurring allows for the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 2):

In your logger code you have print a variable instead of string. just update you code with following

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    console.log('nosuchobject');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventDefault` for preventing form submition:

```js
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```